# QGraphicesItem emit a signal upon hoverEnterEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicswidget

What is the best method/practice for emitting a signal upon entering either a `QGraphicsWidget` or a `QGraphicsItem` ?

In my MWE I would like to trigger a call to `MainWindow.update`, from `Square.hoverEnterEvent`, whenever the user mouse(s) over an item in a QGraphicsScene. The trouble is that `QGraphicsItem/Widget` is not really designed to emit signals. Instead these classes are setup to handle events passed down to them from `QGraphicsScene`. `QGraphicsScene` handles the case that the user has selected an item but does not appear to handle mouse entry events, At least there is no mechanism for `entryEvent` to percolate up to the parent widget/window.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, qApp, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QStatusBar, QGraphicsWidget, QStyle
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QSizeF

class Square(QGraphicsWidget) :
 """
 doc string
 """
 def __init__(self,*args, name = None, **kvps) :
  super().__init__(*args, **kvps)
  self.radius = 5
  self.name = name
  self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

 def sizeHint(self, hint, size):
  size = super().sizeHint(hint, size)
  print(size)
  return QSizeF(50,50)

 def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
  self.initStyleOption(options)
  ink = options.palette.highLight() if options.state == QStyle.State_Selected else options.palette.button()
  painter.setBrush(ink) # ink
  painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), self.radius, self.radius)

 def hoverEnterEvent(self, event) :
  print("Enter Event")
  super().hoverEnterEvent(event)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

 def __init__(self, *args, **kvps) : 
  super().__init__(*args, **kvps)
  # Status bar
  self.stat = QStatusBar(self)
  self.setStatusBar(self.stat)
  self.stat.showMessage("Started")
  # Widget(s)
  self.data = QGraphicsScene(self)
  self.view = QGraphicsView(self.data, self)
  item = self.data.addItem(Square())
  self.view.ensureVisible(self.data.sceneRect())
  self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
  # Visibility
  self.showMaximized()

 def update(self, widget) : 
  self.stat.showMessage(str(widget.name))

if __name__ == "__main__" :
 # Application
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 # Scene Tests
 main = MainWindow()
 main.show()
 # Loop
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The docs state that `QGraphicsItem` is not designed to emit signals, instead it is meant to respond to the events sent to it by `QGraphicsScene`. In contrast it seems  that `QGraphicsWidget` is designed to do so but I'm not entirely sure where the entry point ought to be. Personally I feel `QGraphicsScene` should really be emitting these signals, from what I understand of the design, but am not sure where the entry point ought to be in this case either.

Currently I see the following possible solutions, with #3 being the preferred method. I was wondering if anyone else had a better strategy :

1. Create a `QGraphicsScene` subclass, let's call it `Scene`, to each QGraphicsItem/QGraphicsWidget and call a custom trigger/signal upon the `Scene` from each widget. Here I would have to subclass any item I intend on including within the scene.
2. Set `Mainwindow` up as the event filter for each item in the scene or upon the scene itself and calling `MainWindow.update`.
3. Set `Mainwindow.data` to be a subclass of `QGraphicsScene`, let's call it `Scene`, and let it filter it's own events emitting a `hoverEntry` signal. `hoverEntry` is then connected to `MainWindow.update` as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As Murphy's Law would have it [Ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47142635/958580) already provides an answer.

It seems one should subclass `QGraphicsScene` and add the necessary signal. this is then triggered from the `QGraphicsItem/Widget`. This requires that all items within a scene be sub-classed to ensure that they call the corresponding emit function but it seems must do this do this anyhow when working with the graphics scene stuff.

I'll not mark this as answered for a bit in case some one has a better suggestion.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, qApp, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QStatusBar, QGraphicsWidget, QStyle, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QSizeF, pyqtSignal

class Square(QGraphicsWidget) :
 """
 doc string
 """
 def __init__(self,*args, name = None, **kvps) :
  super().__init__(*args, **kvps)
  self.radius = 5
  self.name = name
  self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
  self.setFlag(self.ItemIsSelectable)
  self.setFlag(self.ItemIsFocusable)

 def sizeHint(self, hint, size):
  size = super().sizeHint(hint, size)
  print(size)
  return QSizeF(50,50)

 def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
  self.initStyleOption(options)
  ink = options.palette.highLight() if options.state == QStyle.State_Selected else options.palette.button()
  painter.setBrush(ink) # ink
  painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), self.radius, self.radius)

 def hoverEnterEvent(self, event) :
  super().hoverEnterEvent(event)
  self.scene().entered.emit(self)
  self.update()

class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene) :
 entered = pyqtSignal([QGraphicsItem],[QGraphicsWidget])


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

 def __init__(self, *args, **kvps) : 
  super().__init__(*args, **kvps)
  # Status bar
  self.stat = QStatusBar(self)
  self.setStatusBar(self.stat)
  self.stat.showMessage("Started")
  # Widget(s)
  self.data = GraphicsScene(self)
  self.data.entered.connect(self.itemInfo)
  self.data.focusItemChanged.connect(self.update)
  self.view = QGraphicsView(self.data, self)
  item = Square(name = "A")
  item.setPos( 50,0)
  self.data.addItem(item)
  item = Square(name = "B")
  item.setPos(-50,0)
  self.data.addItem(item)
  self.view.ensureVisible(self.data.sceneRect())
  self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
  # Visibility
  self.showMaximized()

 def itemInfo(self, item):
  print("Here it is -> ", item)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
 # Application
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 # Scene Tests
 main = MainWindow()
 main.show()
 # Loop
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The magic lines of interest are then the `QGrahicsScene` subclass.

```
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene) :
 entered = pyqtSignal([QGraphicsItem],[QGraphicsWidget])
```

The `QGraphicsWidget.hoverEnterEvent` triggers the `entered` signal. (This is where I got stuck)

```
 def hoverEnterEvent(self, event) :
  ...
  self.scene().entered.emit(self)
  ...
```

And the switcheroo from `self.data = QGraphicsScene(...)`  to `self.data = GraphicsScene` in the `MainWindow`'s init function.